# Why doesn't the STM32F103 have the checkbox "Activate Vbus" for USB device mode in CubeMX?

Tags: stm32f103

I'm studying a task about STM32F103 interface USB in device mode. I see that the STM32F103 doesn't have the checkbox "Activate Vbus" in CubeMX but STM32f105 and STM32f107 have the checkbox. I know that Vbus is important to detect the USB Host.

Please tell me, why is that?

[image: STM32F103]
*STM32F103*
[image: STM32F105]
*STM32F105*

Comment: What's that square next to 'Activate_VBUS" if it's not a checkbox?

Comment: Are you sure that you can connect a USB host to stm32f103 ?

Comment: @BruceAbbott Sorry ! I don't understand your question, could you explain your question in more detail !?

Comment: @MarkoBuršič Yes, i succeeded. I tried to connect Stm32f103 to PC and Android Phone with USB CDC mode and configured stm32f103 by CubeMX. But i don't understand why CubeMX configure USB connectivity stm32f103  without Vbus pin !

Comment: @BruceAbbott the way the OP has formatted the text is confusing. The pic with 'Activate_VBUS' applies to the F105, not the F103.

Answer (score 3):

[STM32F105/107](https://www.st.com/content/st_com/en/products/microcontrollers-microprocessors/stm32-32-bit-arm-cortex-mcus/stm32-mainstream-mcus/stm32f1-series/stm32f105-107/stm32f105rc.html) supports USB OTG.
[STM32F103](https://www.st.com/content/st_com/en/products/microcontrollers-microprocessors/stm32-32-bit-arm-cortex-mcus/stm32-mainstream-mcus/stm32f1-series/stm32f103/stm32f103c8.html) does not. It's simple as that.

Comment: I tried to tell the OP the same. USB_CDC or USB mass storage or USB HID example is not an USB OTG.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič But i studied that VBUS detection is necessary for self-powered devices (https://community.nxp.com/thread/417013 ) !?

Comment: @Chupacabras Stm32f103 still need Vbus to detect USB Host so why it doesn't have the checkbox "Activate Vbus" in CubeMX ?